# Battery status is always not charging

Tags: java, android, status, power-management

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS,
    BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN);

    if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING
        || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL)
        Toast.makeText(context, "Charging!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(context, "Not Charging!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.BatteryReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In this code, the Toast always shows "Not Charging!". I tested this on an actual device, and when I plug it into AC or USB power, it still displays the "Not Charging!" Toast.

Comment: theres something wrong with your intent.getIntExtra, check where this method is being called from and make sure you are setting up intent with the correct parameters

Comment: What's the status you are getting?

Comment: @John I am using it in my manifest.

Comment: @zmbq I get 1 when I unplug and 1 when I plug in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot register for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` via the manifest, so you are not receiving those broadcasts. You are trying to get `BatteryManager` extras from `Intents` that do not have those extras (e.g., `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`). As a result, you are getting the default value of `BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN`.

Comment: So how would I register it programmatically?

Comment: @MohitDeshpande: Call `registerReceiver()`, the same way you would register any other `BroadcastReceiver` programmatically. See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnBattery

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
```

'status' will now be a value between 1 and 5:

```
1 = Unknown
2 = Charging
3 = Discharging
4 = Not Charging
5 = Full
```

Your code:

```
if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING
    || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL) ...
```

can be written:

```
if (status == 2 || status == 5) ...
```

Both are identical because BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING is a constant that *always* equals 2, and BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL is a constant that *always* equals 5.

Comment: Good answer, but please do not use magic numbers in code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad