# BroadcastReceiver allways get not charging

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to detect if device is currently charging or not but this code always sets `isCharging` variable to `false`:

```
public class PowerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

        if (isCharging)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Charging", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Not charging", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically `You cannot register for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED via the manifest`. Register it programmatically

See refer to these links will definitely help :)

[Battery status is always not charging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602833/battery-status-is-always-not-charging)

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnBattery

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: One of your Activity or Service class onResume or onCreate method. Refer here https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/SystemEvents/OnBattery/src/com/commonsware/android/sysevents/battery/BatteryMonitor.java